# I need help figuring out what is wrong with my picture backupcmd

Tags: batch-file

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my code? It should copy files from Pictures to a folder that it will create in "File Copier"

```
@echo off
color 10
title Downloading Info
:: variables
SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
echo off
%backupcmd% "C:\Users\%userprofile%\Pictures\*.jpg" "%drive%\File Copier\Files"
@echo off
cls
```

Comment: this is not php

Comment: Perhaps if you specified your destination drive as `%odrive%` rather than `%drive%` it might work more as you expect.

Comment: This looks like windows batch, not php.

Comment: If `odrive` isn't defined outside of your snippet then `%odrive:~0,2%` also has no value and `odrive` will remain undefined. Additionally it should be either `C:\Users\%UserName%\Pictures\*.jpg` or `%UserProfile%\Pictures\*.jpg`.

Comment: It appears that %userprofile% should've been %USERPROFILE% instead. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Change `"C:\Users\%userprofile%\Pictures\*.jpg"` to `"%USERPROFILE%\pictures\*.jpg"`